# Can I switch audio device for a running program on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, itunes, audio, flash

Is there a way I can switch the audio playback device on Windows XP for a running application such as iTunes or Adobe Flash when those applications lack an interface for changing the playback device?

One option would be to use the audio repeater program within [Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) but that seems so clunky that it is hardly worth it, especially since I would have to buy the software as well.

If you have solutions specific to iTunes or Flash those would be helpful too.

I am already using [STADS](http://www.mp3vcr.com/stads/) to switch audio devices easily, but of course that only changes the default device for programs launched after the switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Windows XP the ability to switch playback devices without an intermediary virtual device like the one used by VAC and its predecessor [VAC3](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac3.htm) is only available on a per-program basis; so the only way to do this for Flash and iTunes output is with audio repeater software.  One free alternative that some people appear to have had success with, though I haven't used it myself, is Virtual Audio Card or [VACard](http://www.datanab.com/audio/VAcard.htm). The program is actually designed to do network streaming but can apparently be made to work.

If your objective is recording while outputting, another use of VAC, there are other programs such as [Mp3myMp3](http://www.mp3mymp3.com/) that will do the job.  Other than that I simply don't know of any equivalent, free software to do the job on XP--I think you're unlikely to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a tool named [Airfoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/windows/). It can hijack audio from specified programs and route it to AirPlay and Airfoil Speaker devices. Just set up Airfoil Speakers on your PC an say it should ouput on your other soundcard. Then open Airfoil and route iTunes to your local Airfoil speaker.